# What would cause all compiler warnings be suppressed for only 1 of multiple projects within a visual studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a Visual Studio 2019 solution comprising of 4 projects. For 3 of the 4 projects, warnings are reported in Visual Studio's Error List window as normal. But for 1 of the 4 projects, all compiler warnings appear to be suppressed and for this 1 project no warnings are being reported in the Error List window at all.

If I introduce an error, that is reported in the Error List window as expected, but not warnings. I have added code that I am certain should cause a warning but still no warning is reported for the affected project.

What could cause all warnings for 1 project to be suppressed? How can I get warnings turned on again for this project?

Answer (score 0):

In Project properties > Compile tab, there is a "Disable all warnings" check box. For this 1 project in the solution it was checked. Unchecking it resolved the problem:

[image: Compile tab]